# Is there a more efficient way to save an Array to SQL than PHP function serialize()?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An efficient way to save an Array and its Keys to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001617/an-efficient-way-to-save-an-array-and-its-keys-to-a-database)

Is there maybe an serialize() equivalent which returns binary?

Saving data as strings is inefficient in both ways: inefficient in a manner of performance and memory. Is there a function to return the pure data from the RAM and accordingly a function to read it back?

Comment: why does it have to be binary?

Comment: array of what? integers? strings?

Comment: I guess he wants to store an arbitrary PHP array in a single database column.  This can be done using `serialize()`, but since its plain-text output is pretty lengthy, he searches for a more compact alternative, which could be binary.

Comment: @Haim: Storing a hashtable (this is what a PHP array is) in a single column of a database is quite different from storing each key in a separate column, hence this question is not a duplicate of your referenced question.

Comment: does he mean efficient in a manner of memory? then `gz_compress()` the serialized array and store it in a blob column

Comment: Saving data as a strings is inefficient in both ways: inefficient in a manner of performance and memory. It would be nice if there would be a function to return the pure data from the RAM.

Comment: "The pure data from the RAM" would be significantly larger in PHP. Arrays incur some overhead in-memory. Each array entry adds 200 bytes (includes a hashsum), as do references to the zval data. The raw RAM structure would also contain pointers that became pointless if written to disk. What you want isn't possible. The string is the compactest format. Otherwise look into pack/unpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is get a more compact representation of the serialized string, e.g., one that uses less space than plain `serialize()`, you might just use [`gzdeflate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) to compress the plain-text output:

```
$data = gzdeflate(serialize($some_array));
// Store in database...

// To restore the array: Get $data from the database, then:
$array = unserialize(gzinflate($data));
```

Instead of `gzdeflate()`/`gzinflate()`, you can also use [`gzcompress()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)/`gzuncompress()`, but these produce slightly larger strings as they include additional metadata such as a checksum.